# How to create a RegEx for something like {{example:bool}}

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I'm creating shortcodes inside an Angular application. To replace the content I'm using regular expressions.

Replacing shortcodes like `{{example}}` to get "example" is working well. For that I'm using the following regex:

`/\{+([^\][]+?)}+/g`

But now the challenge. What if I have a shortcode with this structure: `{{example:bool}}`. I need "example" also in this case. What I tried is not working. This is my version:

`/\{+([^\][]+?):bool}+/g`

But seems to be the wrong way... I also tried it with helper pages like regex101. But everything I try is not the solution I need. I really want to understand this. So if you answer this question, would be awesome to get also an explanation for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You exclude `[` and `]` betweeen `{` and `}`. Exclude the braces. Example: `{+([^{}:]*)(?::([^{}]*))?}+`, see https://regex101.com/r/yiFnxG/1

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. But what if I need the "bool" static to recognize it? For example I have to replace `:bool` with another string as `:color` or `:typography`. Is there a way to get only the :bool strings? With your regex also `{{example:color}}` gets replaced. :)

Comment: `{+([^{}:]*)(?::([^{}]*))?:bool}+` should work. Right? Perfect! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing about matching some strings between two different characters when another string is between them is to exclude the delimiter chars. You exclude `[` and `]` betweeen `{` and `}` while you should be excluding the *braces* themselves.

So, you may use either

```
{+([^{}:]*)(?::([^{}]*))?}+
```

(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yiFnxG/1)) if you plan to match and capture any string inside `{...}` before the first colon (if any) into Group 1 and the part after `:` into Group 2 (again, if any).

If you plan to match a specific word/string at the end of the `{...}` string just use it as part of the regex (you can freely use any literal text as part of the regex):

```
{+([^{}:]*):bool}+
{+([^{}:]*)(?::([^{}]*))?:bool}+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yiFnxG/2) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yiFnxG/3).

The first regex here matches the same way as the first regex in the answer but the part with `:` is not optional. The second regex here matches a second `:` part optionally, before `:bool` obligatory part.

*Details (last regex)*:

- `{+` - one or more `{` chars
- `([^{}:]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `(?::([^{}]*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `([^{}]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `:bool` - a literal text
- `}+` - one or more `}` chars.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!